# Issue in parsing dwarf .debug_info section in an elf file

Tags: c++, linux, elf, dwarf

I am trying to implement a dwarf parser in c++ without using any external dependencies. As mentioned in dwarf5 standard, debug info first 4 bytes or 12 bytes denotes the unit length
Basically this:

```
unit_length (initial length)
A 4-byte or 12-byte unsigned integer representing the length of the3
.debug_info contribution for that compilation unit, not including the length field itself. In the 32-bit DWARF format, this is a 4-byte unsigned integer (which must be less than 0xfffffff0); in the 64-bit DWARF format, this consists of the 4-byte value 0xffffffff followed by an 8-byte unsigned integer that gives the actual length (see Section 7.4 on page 196).
```

When I am dumping .debug_info section hexadecimally using objdump I am getting this(see readelf output below).

objdump -s -j .debug_info hello.o

hello.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .debug_info:

```
 0000 01000000 00000000 9a000000 00000000  ................  
 0010 01000000 00000000 789c9bc6 c0c0c0ca  ........x.......  
 0020 c0c801a4 18984084 2c031a10 42623372  ......@.,...Bb3r  
 0030 b0832916 0805d1c6 c804e5b1 4178ac20  ..).........Ax.  
 0040 8a998535 33af04a8 8115498e 05aa2002  ...53.....I... .  
 0050 8bf18c73 58131918 99394172 4c137318  ...sX....9ArL.s.  
 0060 180011e5 0560
```

So according to this the length should be 0x01000000 but actual length is 0x96.(see readelf output below)
readelf -wi hello.o
Contents of the .debug_info section:

Compilation Unit @ offset 0:
Length:        0x96 (32-bit)
Version:       5
Unit Type:     DW_UT_compile (1)
Abbrev Offset: 0
Pointer Size:  8

I know, I am missing something basic but even after reading standards for many times. I am unable to find my mistake. One more thing, I searched for some basic dwaf parser so that I can understand what they are doing but was unable to find any. All of the parser were big libraries which was difficult to understand. If any of you can atleast provide some readble and understandable parser code, It will be helpful too.

Comment: 0x01000000 is not a number, it is a sequence of bytes. If you want to interpret it as a number, it is probably little-endian, so the number is 0x1. (I don't know the first thing about ELF or DWARF).

Comment: Yeah, Sorry for not mentioning it in the question.

Comment: This is what I have learned in 5 minutes. The .debug_info section contains a sequence of debug information entries (DIE). Each DIE begins with an unsigned LEB128 number containing the abbreviation code for the entry. Abbreviation codes live in .debug_abbrev. unit_length doesn't come into play at this level.

Comment: You are right but that is preceded by the unit header, which consists of the unit length and some other metadata.

Comment: Right you are, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.debug_info` sections are normally *compressed*. `objdump -s` displays compressed data, including the compression header. You are supposed to deal with the compression yourself.

To verify, do this:

```
objcopy --decompress-debug-sections hello.o hello.d.o
objdump -s -j .debug_info hello.d.o
```

You should see data like

```
0000 96000000 05000108 ....
```